# Generating a PDF from Monte carlo Simulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, statistics, static-analysis

If I have an analytical pdf of a generated random variable like this

```
y= (x**(d-1)*e**(-x/g))/(math.gamma(d)*g**d)
```

where d and g are constants

How to generate this pdf using the Monte-Carlo simulation

I substitute with x in the analytical equation and the PDF is generated, however for simulation I don't know how to do

Answer (score 2):

This is [Gamma distribution](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.gamma.html).

Shape would be **d** and scale would be **g**.

Sampling

```
import numpy as np

shape=d
scale=g

s = np.random.gamma(shape, scale, 1000) # draw 1000 RVs from gamma distribution
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, Now if I have that PDf how to simulate it

  f(x)= (x**(shape/2-1) * e**(-np.sqrt(x)/scale)/(2*scale**shape * math.gamma(shape)))

Comment: @MathExplorer Looks like Weibull distribution with shape=1 or a=1/2. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.weibull.html Scale to be adjusted